# Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've created a custom User Attribute called "role" in Azure AD B2C.
I'm trying to update this using `Microsoft.Graph 5.6.0` using this [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-update-properties-of-the-specified-user) approach:

```cs
var user = new User
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
          { $"extension_{_extensionAttributeId}_role", roleName }
    }
};
await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].PatchAsync(user);
```

This results in an exception with the underlying message: `Resource '' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present`
The strange thing is that the message does not even have a Guid in it (as you can see above). So I have no idea what it is complaining about.

I am able to get the user correctly with the below code:

```cs
var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userId].GetAsync();
```

So at least it is able to find the user.

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I just forgot to remove all the `-` from the extension app id. Now it works. ‍♂️